# jQuery set firstChild

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to modify `label` text but it has an `input`, in plain javascript I can do below without losing of the input event.

```js
test.oninput = (e) => console.log(e.target.value)
document.querySelector('label').firstChild.textContent = 'Search: ';
```

```html
<label>
replace me: <input id="test">
</label>
```

But, is there built-in jQuery function to do this?

```js
$('label').first().text('Search') // ???? the input missing
// $('label').children().first().text('Search') // do nothing
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
replace me: <input id="test">
</label>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
$("label").contents().filter(function () {
   return this.nodeType == 3;
})[0].nodeValue = "Search: ";
```

Comment: great `.contents()` is what I looking for, in pure jQuery I should do `$("label").contents().eq(0).text('Search:')` but maybe its not yet implemented

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you include your text in a span

```js
test.oninput = (e) => console.log(e.target.value)
document.querySelector('label span').firstChild.textContent = 'Search: ';
```

```html
<label>
<span>replace me:</span> <input id="test">
</label>
```

```js
$('label span:first').text('Search:');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label>
<span>replace me:</span> <input id="test">
</label>
```

Comment: I will not ask here if I can do that